# Onscreen Keyboard not working in Google Chrome - Works fine in Firefox?

Tags: keyboard, firefox, google-chrome

I've seen old threads on this but when using a touch screen and I click in the address bar of Chrome, the onscreen keyboard does not come up. If I'm using Firefox, it works as expected and OSK comes up fine.

I've seen many reports of this with Chrome but no fixes. Any updates on this?

Old thread:
[Why the Onboard on-screen keyboard doesn't auto-show in google-chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939616/why-the-onboard-on-screen-keyboard-doesnt-auto-show-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering this too. For me, on Gnome Wayland, the onscreen keyboard works correctly in Google Chrome if you swipe up from the bottom of the screen in tablet mode. That should solve your issue. It doesn't appear well documented, but just swipe from the bottom edge of the screen with your keyboard disabled (notebook needs to be in tablet mode) and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The swipe up option is a workaround, but it would be nice if it worked automatically. Like it does with every other window on the computer.